# How to handle theme activation errors?

Tags: theme-development, errors, composer

I am trying to implement the hook for activating a theme, that will install composer dependencies upon activation. In trying to figure out how to handle whether or not the vendor directory exists, I was wondering how to display the dependency errors if they occur, and what I can show instead of just a broken site. Also is there a way to maybe rollback to last theme, and send a notification that the theme is not able to be installed on the users system?

Comment: This is a highly unusual approach. Why aren't the composer dependencies included in the theme folder? How are you going to run the install command from within WordPress? Is your theme going to require that users have Composer installed on their hosting? Most hosts won't have this. A simpler approach would be to bundle the dependencies as part of a build step before distribution. Then the user can install the theme as easily as any other.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you elaborate? The problem I am having is that I am distributing this to end-users who are not savvy enough to build from a source. So what I am trying to do is make this as seamless as possible by allowing them to simply activate the theme, and if composer is not available or any other system restriction is in place, that the errors would notify them of such restrictions, and then advise them to contact a dev for support.